# how to remove default black list divider in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, header

I have the following two headers that I hide until an li is added and then these headers appear above their respective listviews. The theming is such that they are blue with the gradient, but I want the black list-divider that appears between them by default to not show. Any tips?

```
<div id="header1" data-role="header" hidden="true" >
    <ul class="ui-li ui-bar-b ui-first-child" id="list1" data-role="list-divider" role="heading"><h2><center>Selected Symptoms</center></h2></ul>
    <ul class="ui-li ui-bar-b ui-first-child" id="list2" data-role="list-divider" role="heading"><h2><center>Selected Symptoms</center></h2></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using jQuery Mobile, aren't you?

Comment: yes, forgot ot include that

Comment: Do you know how to make a valid HTML document? I dont belive so. <h2> in <ul>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @wumm says, it is not valid HTML to have an `<h2>` tag directly inside a `<ul>` tag. You need to wrap the `<h2>` in a `<li>` first.

But in answer to your question on hiding the list markers, I think you can try adding `list-style:none;` to the `<ul>` styles.